# Global Tomcat 8 DataSource resource closed before `ServletContextListener.contextDestroyed()` is executed

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, datasource, jndi

I deployed a web application onto Tomcat 8. In that application a global JNDI `DataSource` is defined that is shared between several servlets. Inside the application it is wrapped within a *Spring* bean which uses a *factory method* to retrieve that once from JNDI. There is also a `ServletContextListener` implemented to react when the web applications context gets destroyed. The application itself works fine and the `DataSource` can be properly retrieved and used.

**The Problem**: On a Tomcat shutdown (`catalina.sh stop`, `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM`) the `DataSource` gets closed before the `ServletContextListener.contextDestroyed()` is invoked. That is bad because I need to access the DB in that method (e.g. to shutdown our Quartz scheduler properly which has database access).

Here is a snippet of the `server.xml`:

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    ...
    <GlobalNamingResources>
        ...
        <Resource name="myDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000" username="" password=""
            removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60"  driverClassName="org.h2.Driver"
            url="jdbc:h2:myApp" defaultTransactionIsolation="READ_COMMITTED" />
        ...
    </GlobalNamingResources>
    ...
</Server>
```

Here from the `context.xml`:

```
<Context path="/myApp" docBase="myApp"
    reloadable="false" crossContext="false" antiResourceLocking="true" unloadDelay="5000">
    <ResourceLink name="jdbc/myDB" global="myDB" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
    <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManager"
        distributable="false" saveOnRestart="false">
        <Store className="org.apache.catalina.session.FileStore"/>
    </Manager>
</Context>
```

Here a snippet of my `ServletContextListener`:

```
public class MyListener implements ServletContextListener {
...
    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        ...
        // using the DataSource here
        ...
    }
...
}
```

In the logs I can see an `Exception` when I try to use the `DataSource` in the `ServletContextListener` saying that the Data source is already closed:

```
05 Aug 2015 14:59:17,915 [localhost-startStop-2] () || DEBUG   DisposableBeanAdapter: Invoking destroy method 'close' on bean with name 'dataSource'
05-Aug-2015 14:59:17.918 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.close Failed to unregister the JMX name: Catalina:type=DataSource,class=javax.sql.DataSource,name="myDB"
 javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: Catalina:type=DataSource,class=javax.sql.DataSource,name="myDB"
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.exclusiveUnregisterMBean(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.unregisterMBean(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.unregisterMBean(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.close(BasicDataSource.java:1916)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.invokeCustomDestroyMethod(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:327)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:742)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:455)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1090)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:586)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4776)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5390)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1424)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1413)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
...
Shutting down scheduler.
...
05 Aug 2015 14:59:24,098 [QuartzScheduler_DefaultQuartzScheduler-4424f282be6c1438786703813_ClusterManager] () || ERROR   JobStoreTX          : ClusterManager: Error managing cluster: Failed to obtain DB connection from data source 'qrtzds': java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve datasource via JNDI url 'java:comp/env/jdbc/myDB' java.sql.SQLException: Data source is closed
org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Failed to obtain DB connection from data source 'qrtzds': java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve datasource via JNDI url 'java:comp/env/jdbc/myDB' java.sql.SQLException: Data source is closed [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve datasource via JNDI url 'java:comp/env/jdbc/myDB' java.sql.SQLException: Data source is closed]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:778)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.getNonManagedTXConnection(JobStoreTX.java:71)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doCheckin(JobStoreSupport.java:3245)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.manage(JobStoreSupport.java:3858)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.run(JobStoreSupport.java:3895)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve datasource via JNDI url 'java:comp/env/jdbc/myDB' java.sql.SQLException: Data source is closed
    at org.quartz.utils.JNDIConnectionProvider.getConnection(JNDIConnectionProvider.java:163)
    at org.quartz.utils.DBConnectionManager.getConnection(DBConnectionManager.java:108)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:775)
    ... 4 more
```

**Question**:

- How can I control the lifecycle of Tomcat to close the global `DataSource` resource *after* the web application context is destroyed?
- How can I tell Spring to *not* invoke the `BasicDataSource.close()` method? I tried to set the bean attribute `destroy-method` to an empty value. But it seems that when that is empty it still invokes the `close()` method [because it detects an `AutoClosable`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-disposablebean).